# Cannot resolve maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven

In my project I have added the following two dependencies in my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>antlr</groupId>
    <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Still while building, maven is not able to find the above two dependencies. I am getting the below error:

```
[INFO] The following files have NOT been resolved:
[INFO]    antlr:antlr:jar:sources:2.7.7:compile
[INFO]    oracle:ojdbc6:jar:sources:11.2.0.3:compile
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You can try this. If you are using Eclipse then right click on project then Maven->Update Project...

Comment: First this does not look like an error (Only INFO level)...furthermore if you really have one please post the full log output...

Comment: What also comes into my mind. The output shows that you requested the source packaged which do not exist for all artifacts in Maven central or other repositories...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this one :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

you have to add this repository in your settings.xml :

```
<repository>
    <id>maven.oracle.com</id>
    <name>oracle-maven-repo</name>
    <url>https://maven.oracle.com</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
    <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
    </releases>
</repository>
```

create an oracle account (it's free) and add it to servers block in settings.xml :

```
    <server>
        <id>maven.oracle.com </id>
        <username>username</username>
        <password>password</password>
        <configuration>
            <basicAuthScope>
                <host>ANY</host>
                <port>ANY</port>
                <realm>OAM 11g</realm>
            </basicAuthScope>
            <httpConfiguration>
                <all>
                    <params>
                        <property>
                            <name>http.protocol.allow-circular-redirects </name>
                            <value>%b,true</value>
                        </property>
                    </params>
                </all>
            </httpConfiguration>
        </configuration>
    </server>
```

For the second I need more detail about the error messages. please give me the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

There is no [ojdbc6](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cojdbc6) in Maven Central.

Note that it is only the **sources** which it says it cannot download. Sometimes projects have missing source from the project.

Comment: OJDBC6 is available [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/oracle/ojdbc6/11.2.0.3)

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below link to get an idea of how to use OJDBC into your application.
[This link might help solving your problem](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-add-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-your-maven-local-repository/)